# OpenGL ES and Thread Structure

Tags: android, design-patterns, opengl-es

I have the following (simplified) rig so far:

**MyActivity.java:**

```java
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
public GLSurfaceView myGLView;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      myGLView = new MyGLSurfaceView(this);
      setContentView(myGLView);
   }
}
```

**MyGLSurfaceView.java:**

```java
public class MyGLSurfaceView extends GLSurfaceView {
   private MyRenderer mMyRenderer = new MyRenderer();
   private MyThread mMyThread = new MyThread();

   public MyView(Context context) {
      super(context);
      setRenderer(mGameRenderer);
      setRenderMode(GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_CONTINUOUSLY);
      mGameThread.setRunning(true);
   }
}
```

**MyRenderer.java:**

```java
public class GameRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {
    @Override
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
       gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
       // ...
    }
}
```

**MyThread.java:**

Here I'm doing all initializations, creating objects and so on.

```java
public class MyThread extends Thread {
    private MyObject mMyObject = new MyObject();
    public MyThread {
       // ...
       mMyObject.setRot();
       this.start();
    }

    public void run() {
       // Fixed Timestep Loop goes here
       mMyObject.getRot();
    }
}
```

**MyObject.java:**

This is a sample object which holds different fileds and methods.

```java
public class MyObject  {
   private double mRot;

   // Getters & Setters
   protected double getRot() { return mRot; }

   protected void setRot() {
      // ... Do calculations
   }

   public void draw() {
      // OGL Instructions go here
      gl.glRotatef(1.2f, 0, 0, setRot());
   }
}
```

Now the problem I was running into is the following: (I guess, I missed something very basic and simple :) )
As stated above, I'm creating my object instances in the MyThread class. The Thread is created in the MyGLSurface class, same goes for the Renderer. Now, that I have that two threads I can't figure out, how to use that one instance and their methods in that two separate threads.
I tried different approaches, but nothing did work. So in my opinion I made a mistake in the class design. I mean, I don't just want to get it running (that'd be quite easy), but I want to know how to do it correctly.
The main problem is actually that I can't access the MyObject's instance and simply use the draw() method in the renderer - because I don't get it.

I thought, it would be possible to call the draw() method of MyObject within the rendering thread without the need of using a singleton and so on. So simply referencing the instance to it. But somehow that seemed weird and dirty (besides that it doesn't work for me).
I tried dozens of different approaches, but I really need a bump into the right direction. I'm quite familar with OOP, but here I might really miss something.

In that many samples I found on the web (stackoverflow, Replica Island, different tutorial sites, Google I/O, DevCentral, etc.) they either didn't use a multithreaded system or they split it directly (GL objects from regular objects).

Any hint into the right direction would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another example to peruse:

https://code.google.com/p/android-breakout/

The wiki and code comments discuss the threading issues inherent in using `GLSurfaceView`.  In particular, the game does as much setup as it can before the Renderer thread starts; once it's running, as much work as possible is done on that thread.  The game state objects are effectively "owned" by the renderer thread, and the Activity is owned by the UI thread, so any "off-thread" interactions are handled by sending messages rather than making direct method calls.  For example, see the [handling of touch events](https://code.google.com/p/android-breakout/source/browse/src/com/faddensoft/breakout/GameSurfaceView.java#75).

It's good that you're thinking about this -- you either need synchronization or careful object discipline to avoid nasty race conditions.

See also: [android game loop vs updating in the rendering thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14077403/android-game-loop-vs-updating-in-the-rendering-thread/14347463#14347463)

Answer (score 0):

The nice thing about GLSurfaceView is that it creates the OpenGL rendering thread for you, so you don't need to create one yourself.  The main UI thread will call the OnDraw() method in your view class and that's all the threads you need.  If you really want to create your own thread for OpenGL rendering, use TextureView instead of GLSurfaceView.  Here is an article that I think will help:

```
http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/porting-opengl-games-to-android-on-intel-atom-processors-part-1
```